# Connect to url in the background and loop through elements

Tags: java, url, search, getelementbyid

Is it possible, using java,  to connect to a url in the background (without a visual interface) and loop through the elements of that link? I'd like to make an automated search tool for personal use. Go to a specific url, loop through the elements reading their text, and when I get a match for what I'm searching, perform a click type operation on the match to start a download. If "clicking" on a view is not easy I'm good with just getting the url that this view links to.

Comment: The #Anonymous hackers maybe know the answer well !:)

Comment: you can use selenium (headless) and phantomjs for this like here [example](https://itkosmopolit.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/quick-start-of-running-selenium-webdriver-against-phantomjs-in-java-on-windows/)

Comment: You can use HTML parser like [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse page. But if you want to simulate clicking which would involve JavaScript then I would consider web driver like Selenium.

Comment: Do you have to use Java?

Comment: I'd like to incorporate it to an android app so...yeah I'd prefer it in java. Do you have something else to recommend?

Comment: @Anonymous I could not help but notice that you have not accepted answers to many of your questions.  Some people may be reluctant to assist you when this is the case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed you mentioned you want this for Android, but here is something I wrote in Python 3.4 with a similar approach.  Perhaps you can create something similar in Java as an Android app.

You will need to do some web requests (In my case with Python I am using the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library) and screen scraping (I am using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)). In this particular instance I had to navigate around some 302 redirects, so I have multiple calls to the "get" function in [Session()](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#session-objects). I do not do any downloads in this example, however.

This is a (stripped down) example that performs the tasks of navigating to the website, logging in ("clicking" the submit button is done by POSTing the form data), scraping the screen for data, and printing it to the console.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

credentials = {
    'field1':'valueForField1',
    'field2':'valueForField2'
    ...
}

s = requests.Session()

r0 = s.get('http://www.foobar.com')
r1 = s.get('http://www.foobar.com/foo')
...
r21 = s.post('http://www.foobar.com/foo/bar.do', data=credentials)
...
r23 = s.get('http://www.foobar.com/foo/bar/accountinfo')

soup = BeautifulSoup(r23.text)
product = soup.find_all('td', class_='product')

print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print()

for p in product:
    print(p)

print()
print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
```

Comment: this seems promising...I'll give it a try. after i figure out how to import python in my app !

Comment: You don't necessarily have to you use Python.  I've never done any screen scraping in Java, but http://jsoup.org/ that Pshemo suggested might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
Look up URLConnection class and HttpURLConnection class.

Just did a search "URLConnection example" and got this:

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=401

It looks simple enough to follow.

Comment: can you give more info on how that helps with looping through the url elements? or a working example perhaps ?